# SQL Query to Set Multiple XML Elements with Custom Attribute Names

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

My requirement is to return a single xml result by converting a SQL query which returns multiple elements in the result.

So the SQL Query is as below,

```
SELECT 'z_milestonetype' AS 'ColumnValue/@name',  
(select
task_milestone as milestone from PLAN where
request_id='1173' and task_milestone='PC') AS ColumnValue,  null,
'z_actual_finish' AS 'ColumnValue/@name',  
(select effect_dttm as
effect_dttm from PLAN where request_id='1173' and
task_milestone='PC') AS ColumnValue,  null FOR XML PATH ('')
```

This actually returns an XML like below

```
<ColumnValue name="z_milestonetype">LM_EQ</ColumnValue>
<ColumnValue name="z_actual_finish">2020-07-15T18:30:00</ColumnValue>
```

Since the result retrieves only one result, this seems to work fine but my requirement is to set the XML with iterating values. Please see below XML code.

```
    <customObjectInstances objectCode="zsinboundtask">
          <instance instanceCode="-1" objectCode="zinboundtask">
            <CustomInformation>
              <ColumnValue name="partition_code">NIKU.ROOT</ColumnValue>
              <ColumnValue name="page_layout">odf.znecinboundtaskFrame</ColumnValue>
              <ColumnValue name="name">-1</ColumnValue>
              <ColumnValue name="code">-1</ColumnValue>               
              <ColumnValue name="z_milestonetype">TEST2</ColumnValue>
              <ColumnValue name="z_finish">2020-09-25T18:30:00</ColumnValue>
            </CustomInformation>
          </instance>
          <instance instanceCode="-1" objectCode="zinboundtask">
            <CustomInformation>
              <ColumnValue name="partition_code">NIKU.ROOT</ColumnValue>
              <ColumnValue name="page_layout">odf.znecinboundtaskFrame</ColumnValue>
              <ColumnValue name="name">-1</ColumnValue>
              <ColumnValue name="code">-1</ColumnValue>                
              <ColumnValue name="z_milestonetype">TEST</ColumnValue>
              <ColumnValue name="z_finish">2020-09-25T18:30:00</ColumnValue>
            </CustomInformation>
          </instance>       
 ………    
        </customObjectInstances>
```

If I use the same query as above to set the values for multiple rows, this would show the error Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
SELECT
'-1' AS 'instance/@instanceCode', 'zinboundtask' AS 'instance/@objectCode',
null,
 null,
 'partition_code' AS 'ColumnValue/@name', 
'NIKU.ROOT' AS ColumnValue,
 null,
 'page_layout' AS 'ColumnValue/@name', 
'odf.zinboundtaskFrame' AS ColumnValue,
 null,
 'name' AS 'ColumnValue/@name', 
'-1' AS ColumnValue,
 null,
 'code' AS 'ColumnValue/@name', 
'-1' AS ColumnValue,
 null,
'z_milestonetype' AS 'ColumnValue/@name', 
(select task_milestone as milestone from PLAN where request_id='1173') AS ColumnValue,
 null,
'z_finish' AS 'ColumnValue/@name', 
(select effect_dttm as effect_dttm from PLAN where request_id='1173') AS ColumnValue,
 null
FOR XML PATH ('CustomInformation')
```

As explained,

1. I need to have the XML formatted with the custom attributes
2. Meantime I need to display the elements from the select query in the given xml format

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Hi @marc_s I'm using MS-SQL Server here. Already added the tag

Comment: @SarangaAmaraweera, you need to provide a **DDL and sample data population for the source table(s)** via T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [text()] tag, like this:

```
select name as '@name' , o.object_id as [text()]
from sys.objects o
for xml path('ColumnValue')
```

If you had posted some sample data i'm sure we could spin your query around.

Comment: Hi @Mitz, the sample output has been already posted in my question, please check the second xml that I have shared. :) 1st tag should be the root node and in the second tag , it should be repeated. (Both need to be hard coded). Again in the <CustomInformation> tag, I need to have the first 3 items to be hard coded.  From next line onward, I need to have the values from sql select query with the given format.

Comment: yes, i see the output but i don't have the tables and some data to test my query against it. I'd just be coding blindly.

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for a DDL and sample data population, here is a conceptual example for you.

You just need to add all your columns, add `WHERE` clause logic, etc.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, partition_code VARCHAR(30), page_layout VARCHAR(50), z_finish DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @tbl (partition_code, page_layout, z_finish) VALUES
(   'NIKU.ROOT', 'odf.znecinboundtaskFrame', '2020-09-25T18:30:00'),
(   'NIKU.BOOT', 'odf.inboundtaskFrame', '2018-01-25T22:20:00');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT (
    SELECT 'partition_code' as 'ColumnValue/@name', partition_code as [ColumnValue]
        , ''
        , 'page_layout' as 'ColumnValue/@name', page_layout as [ColumnValue]
        , ''
        , 'z_finish' as 'ColumnValue/@name', z_finish as [ColumnValue]
    FROM @tbl
    FOR XML PATH('CustomInformation'), TYPE
).query('<customObjectInstances objectCode="zsinboundtask">
{
    for $x in CustomInformation
    return <instance instanceCode="-1" objectCode="zinboundtask">
        {$x}
    </instance>
}
</customObjectInstances>')
```

**Output**

```
<customObjectInstances objectCode="zsinboundtask">
  <instance instanceCode="-1" objectCode="zinboundtask">
    <CustomInformation>
      <ColumnValue name="partition_code">NIKU.ROOT</ColumnValue>
      <ColumnValue name="page_layout">odf.znecinboundtaskFrame</ColumnValue>
      <ColumnValue name="z_finish">2020-09-25T18:30:00</ColumnValue>
    </CustomInformation>
  </instance>
  <instance instanceCode="-1" objectCode="zinboundtask">
    <CustomInformation>
      <ColumnValue name="partition_code">NIKU.BOOT</ColumnValue>
      <ColumnValue name="page_layout">odf.inboundtaskFrame</ColumnValue>
      <ColumnValue name="z_finish">2018-01-25T22:20:00</ColumnValue>
    </CustomInformation>
  </instance>
</customObjectInstances>
```